# Spring Context startup, silence preamble

Tags: spring, log4j

I'm running a command line application. I'm running Lo4j2. Everything works, but I would like to silence the Spring preamble that seems to run before Log4J has been loaded. Let me be clear, Log4J is working correctly, but the preamble of Spring logging messages arrives as soon as the application context is loaded.

i.e. I DON'T want to see this

`Oct 24, 2015 9:07:29 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@42a48628: startup date [Sat Oct 24 09:07:29 BST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 24, 2015 9:07:29 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [springConfig.xml]`

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must have following dependencies:* including log4j-1.2-api*

```
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j',  name: 'log4j', version: log4j2_version
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: log4j2_version
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-1.2-api', version: log4j2_version   
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: log4j_slfj_binder_version
```

Have your log4j2.xml configured like this. I tested with Log4j2

```
 <Configuration >
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern=">%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] %X{trxID} %.20X{userName}[%c{2}] %m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>


  <Loggers>
     <Logger name="org.springframework.context.support" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" level="ERROR"/>
    </Logger>
     <Logger name="org.springframework.beans.factory.xml" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" level="ERROR"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="INFO" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My Test Program :

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class TestLog {

    String springConfig = "spring-config/insight-test-context.xml";

    private static final Logger slf4jLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestLog.class);

    private AbstractApplicationContext ctx;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLog().doTest();
    }

    public void doTest() {
        slf4jLogger.info("--------Staring TestLog---------------");
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);
        ctx.registerShutdownHook();
        slf4jLogger.info("----------Completed TestLog------------");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but it doesn't work for me. Perhaps you need to test for log4j2. Note: it's only the preamble that I need to get rid of.

Comment: Hi Amit - I thank you kindly for your response, but this doesn't work. I tried this kind of thing. It seems that during ClassPathXmlApplicationContext until the XmlBeanDefinitionReader reads the springConfig.xml, logging is not going to log4J.

Comment: Hey, this sample code makes sure that logger context is initialized before spring context does. Also, wanted to double check you have log4j-1.2-api jar.